# Neo4j procedure "The requested operation cannot be performed, because it has to be performed in a transaction..."

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, transactions, graph-databases

I am writing the following procedure for Neo4j 3.3.5:

```
/**
 * This procedure provides best sell products from a category
 *
 * @param category the category node for which we are searching for best sell items
 * @param limit    limit of returned products count
 */
@Procedure(value = "bestSell.category")
@Description("Get best sell items from a specified category")
public Stream<OutputResult> bestSellForCategory(
        @Name("category") Node category,
        @Name(value = "limit", defaultValue = "20") Long limit) {
    RelationshipType inCategoryType = RelationshipType.withName(IN_CATEGORY_RELATION);
    RelationshipType recentlyOrderedType = RelationshipType.withName(RECENTLY_ORDERED_RELATION);

    try {
        List<Node> productsInCateogory = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ScoredResult> scoredProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Relationship relationship : category.getRelationships(inCategoryType, Direction.INCOMING)) {
            Node product = relationship.getOtherNode(category);
            productsInCateogory.add(product);
        }

        productsInCateogory.parallelStream().forEach(node -> {
            long i = 0;
            for (Relationship ignored : node.getRelationships(recentlyOrderedType, Direction.INCOMING)) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                scoredProducts.add(new ScoredResult((Long) node.getProperty(DOC_ID_PROPERTY), i));
            }
        });
        return scoredProducts.stream().sorted((scoredResult, t1) -> (int) (scoredResult.score - t1.score)).limit(limit).map(s -> new OutputResult(s.docId));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is the test I written for the procedure:

```
@Test
public void checkBestSellOutput() throws Throwable {
    try (Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4j.boltURI(), Config.build().withoutEncryption().toConfig())) {
        Session session = driver.session();

        try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
            tx.run(
                    "MERGE (c:Category {categoryId:93})" +
                            "MERGE (p1:Product {docId:1})" +
                            "MERGE (p2:Product {docId:2})" +
                            "MERGE (p3:Product {docId:3})" +
                            "MERGE (p1)-[:IN_CATEGORY]->(c)" +
                            "MERGE (p2)-[:IN_CATEGORY]->(c)" +
                            "MERGE (p3)-[:IN_CATEGORY]->(c)" +
                            "MERGE (cust1:Customer {customerId:1})" +
                            "MERGE (cust2:Customer {customerId:2})" +
                            "MERGE (cust1)-[:RECENTLY_ORDERED]->(p1)" +
                            "MERGE (cust2)-[:RECENTLY_ORDERED]->(p1)" +
                            "MERGE (cust1)-[:RECENTLY_ORDERED]->(p2)");
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        List<Record> results = session.run("MATCH (c:Category {categoryId: 93}) CALL bestSell.category(c, 20) YIELD docId RETURN docId").list();

        assertThat(results.size(), equalTo(2));
    }
}
```

When I try to run build with maven, I get the following error: 
Failed to invoke procedure `bestSell.category`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested operation cannot be performed, because it has to be performed in a transaction. Ensure you are wrapping your operation in the appropriate transaction boilerplate and try again.

I tried a lot and did not find answer in documentation. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Transaction](https://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.3/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html) JavaDoc for the simple boilerplate:

> ```
>  try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
>  {
>      // operations on the graph
>      // ...
>
>      tx.success();
>  }
> ```

Here is an example of how you can use the boilerplate in your procedure. The `@Context` annotation will cause the `db` variable to be injected with the appropriate `GraphDatabaseService` instance at runtime.

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Context;
.
.
.

@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;

/**
 * This procedure provides best sell products from a category
 *
 * @param category the category node for which we are searching for best sell items
 * @param limit    limit of returned products count
 */
@Procedure(value = "bestSell.category")
@Description("Get best sell items from a specified category")
public Stream<OutputResult> bestSellForCategory(
        @Name("category") Node category,
        @Name(value = "limit", defaultValue = "20") Long limit) {
    RelationshipType inCategoryType = RelationshipType.withName(IN_CATEGORY_RELATION);
    RelationshipType recentlyOrderedType = RelationshipType.withName(RECENTLY_ORDERED_RELATION);

    try {
        List<Node> productsInCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ScoredResult> scoredProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            for (Relationship relationship : category.getRelationships(inCategoryType, Direction.INCOMING)) {
                Node product = relationship.getOtherNode(category);
                productsInCategory.add(product);
            }
            productsInCategory.parallelStream().forEach(node -> {
                long i = 0;
                for (Relationship ignored : node.getRelationships(recentlyOrderedType, Direction.INCOMING)) {
                    i++;
                }
                if (i != 0) {
                    scoredProducts.add(new ScoredResult((Long) node.getProperty(DOC_ID_PROPERTY), i));
                }
            });
            tx.success();
        }

        return scoredProducts.stream().sorted((scoredResult, t1) -> (int) (scoredResult.score - t1.score)).limit(limit).map(s -> new OutputResult(s.docId));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```